# Is it possible to use brace expansion and globbing together?

Tags: shell, expansion, globbing

Say I wanted to copy the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in each user's `/home` directory to `/tmp` (for whatever reason). I figured I could use globbing and brace expansion to do this quickly, but I ran into trouble. I tried using something like `key_for_{*}` to get a different file name for each user. My thought was that I could copy everything like this,

```
sudo cp */.ssh/authorized_keys /tmp/key_for_{*}
```

I expected `/tmp` to have files like `/tmp/key_for_alice`, `/tmp/key_for_james`, &c... but that's not what happened.

Googling about I found plenty of examples of brace expansion but none that addressed this question. Is there something I should know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not brace expansion. That's just... an asterisk inside braces. You'll need to use a for loop for this.

```
for user in *
do
  cp "$user"/.ssh/authorized_keys /tmp/key_for_"$user"
done
```